# Ошибка: [Error] Unit1.pas(32): Undeclared identifier: 'GetInetFile'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой на Delphi 7.
Вот кусок кода:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var FileOnNet, LocalFileName: string ;

 begin

     FileOnNet:='URL My';
       LocalFileName:='my.my';

       if GetInetFile(FileOnNet,LocalFileName)=True then
          ShowMessage('Download successful')
       else
          ShowMessage('Error in file download');
    end;
```

Вот, а проблема компилятора такова:

> [Error] Unit1.pas(32): Undeclared identifier: 'GetInetFile'

В чем проблема? В Uses модуль подключен.

Comment: @marambola, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Суть ошибки вы, вроде бы, поняли. Убедитесь, что точно нужный модуль подключен в секции USES.
Убедитесь, что имя функции вы написали в нужном регистре.
Убедитесь также, что функция принимает именно такие параметры. 
Попробуйте зажать CTRL и кликнуть мышью по имени.

Comment: регистр ни при чем.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете функцию **GetInetFile**, а она у вас нигде не описана. Тут 2 варианта: или писать самому функцию, или копировать оттуда, где вы скопипастили остальной код. И USES здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Uses здесь вполне причем.